# Ubuntu - Full screen mode not changing resolution

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, guest-additions

I'm running Ubuntu inside [virtualbox.](http://www.virtualbox.org/)  For some reason I can't get the window resolution to change.  On my Windows 7 computer the resolution changes automatically just by adjusting the window.

On this XP machine I'm not getting any resolution changes after installing the guest addons.

Any idea how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: Did you reboot after installing guest additions?

Comment: @binfalse yes I did.  I did run the install using terminal via "sudo path\VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run".  On the other machine I might have run it by clicking the "Open autorun prompt", but I dont remember.

Comment: Something might be buggy with the guest additions (or with their compat to the ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating to 4.0.6 virtulbox and reinstalling the guest applications, it still did not work.

So, I went into System Menu > Preferences > Monitors > and I manually changed the resolution to 1600x1200.  Now when I maximize teh screen it utilizes the full screen.

I'm not sure why I had to manually change the resolution here, when I did not on my home computer.  But, this worked.

Comment: on 2/2/2011 I got a notification from Ubuntu saying that I could update my OS.  I updated the OS and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote in ubuntu terminal `xrandr -s 1980x1050` and it worked instantly.